# How to summarize size of a specific file name over a folder recursively

Tags: hdfs, byte, summarize

I need to find out how many bytes (unique) are used by specifice files on the hdfs (for example all pdf's) in a folder with loads of subfolders..

I have tried some code but didn't find a good answer. I am not good with linux shell coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HDFS commands and Linux commands to find the summary/total size of files with specific types in HDFS.

For example, you can list down the similar filetypes using a command like below, (`.txt` type in the below example). Note that the files are present in both `/tmp` and `/tmp/test/`

```
hdfs dfs -ls -R /tmp/|grep .txt
-rw-r--r--   3 root   supergroup         70 2019-09-11 05:27 /tmp/test/testing1.txt
-rw-r--r--   3 root   supergroup         30 2019-09-11 05:27 /tmp/testing.txt
-rw-r--r--   3 root   supergroup         70 2019-09-11 05:31 /tmp/testing1.txt
```

To get the total size of these files, we need to sum up the size of each files, i.e., the fifth column of the above output. This can be done using a command like below,

```
hdfs dfs -ls -R /tmp/|grep .txt|awk '{ total += $5 }; END { print total }'
170
```

**170 Bytes** (70+30+70) is the total size occupied by all the `.txt` files under the HDFS directory `/tmp/` .

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you very much! i've added the -h opion to get it in mb but this works perfect for me!

Comment: Yes `h` will give the size in human readable format. It also gives in GB when the file size is large.

Comment: Glad it helped!